# Symfony3.4 controller called but nothing happens after redirection

Tags: symfony-3.4

Here is the first question I published. I hope that you'll be able to help me.
My problem is described in the title but lets be more accurate:
I'm using PHP7.2 and Symfony3.4
Ive got a standard form whose redirect action is the following:

```
/**
     * @Route("/giveMetiers/{newAgent}", name="giveMetiers")
     * @param $newAgent
     * @return Response
     */
    public function giveMetiersAction($newAgent)
    {
        $agent = $this->getProfil();

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(
            $this->render(
                'AgentBundle:Templates:blank.html.twig',
                [
                    "agent" => $agent,
                    "url" => $this->generateUrl(
                        'giveMetiersCorpus',
                        ["newAgent" => $newAgent]
                    ),
                    "title" => "Attribuer des métiers"
                ]
            )
            ->getContent()
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

The function giveMetierCorpus is the following:

```
/**
     * @Route("/giveMetiersCorpus{newAgent}", name="giveMetiersCorpus")
     * @param $newAgent
     * @return Response
     */
    public function giveMetiersCorpusAction($newAgent)
    {
        //Some business logic..

        $template = $this->render(
            'AgentBundle:SuperAgent:giveMetiers.html.twig',
            [
                "poles" => $poles,
                "newAgent" => $newagent,
                "metiers" => $metiers,
                "constMetier" => $constMetier,
                "constCompetence" => $constCompetence
            ]
        )
        ->getContent();

        $json = json_encode($template);
        $response = new Response($json, 200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
```

Well, everything works, my view got called properly and a new form is then displayed. Here comes trouble. When i submit this new form, the executed action is:

```
/**
     * @Route("/updateMetiersAgent", name="updateMetiersAgent")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function updateMetiersAgent(Request $request)
    {
        //Business logics..

        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl(
                'giveCompetences',
                ["newAgent" => $agent->getId()]
            )
        );
    }
```

Which calls giveCompetences..:

```
/**
     * @Route("/giveCompetences/{newAgent}", name="giveCompetences")
     * @param $newAgent
     * @return Response
     */
    public function giveCompetencesAction($newAgent)
    {
        $agent = $this->getProfil();

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(
            $this->render(
                'AgentBundle:Templates:blank.html.twig',
                [
                    "agent" => $agent,
                    "url" => $this->generateUrl(
                        'giveCompetencesCorpus',
                        ["newAgent" => $newAgent]
                    ),
                    "title" => "Attribuer des competences"
                ]
            )
            ->getContent()
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

Here, the fonction giveCompetencesCorpus isnt called... I give you this function:

```
/**
     * @Route("/giveCompetencesCorpus{newAgent}", name="giveCompetencesCorpus")
     * @param $newAgent
     * @return Response
     */
    public function giveCompetencesCorpusAction($newAgent)
    {
        //Business Logic

        $template = $this->render(
            'AgentBundle:SuperAgent:giveCompetences.html.twig',
            [
                "poles" => $poles,
                "newAgent" => $newagent,
                "technos" => $listeTechnos,
                "constMetier" => $constMetier,
                "constCompetence" => $constCompetence
            ]
        )
        ->getContent();

        $json = json_encode($template);
        $response = new Response($json, 200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
```

I really dont understand why this isn't call.
I even tried to directly call this last function directly as an action from my form, i see that the function is called but nothing happens, nothing got render to the page.
Does anyone got the solution of this problem please?

Best Regards,

Maxime

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten the slash before the placeholder in your route

```
@Route("/giveCompetencesCorpus{newAgent}", name="giveCompetencesCorpus")
```

Should probably be something like

```
@Route("/giveCompetencesCorpus/{newAgent}", name="giveCompetencesCorpus")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but that was not the problem (I've already tried this way).
I finally figured out the problem (but still I don't know why..)
The first form was built with real  TAG and a submit button while the second was submitted using a Javascript FormData (the code was originally not written by me).
That was apparently the problem, when I changed the behavior of this form using a "normal form" everything was then going right.
However, if someone know the real underlying reason of this "bug" I'm interested in :)

Maxime